# Как парсить пользователей с био из группы Телеграм

Tags: python, парсер, telegram

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from collections import namedtuple
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest

api_id = int()
api_hash = ''
phone = ''
limit = 10000


client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    full = await client(GetFullUserRequest('username'))
    bio = full.full_user.about
    print(bio)
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

вот код который находит био по username но мне надо чтобы по id и в дополнение к этому я никак не могу спрасить группы
Есть много ответов в SO но они уже на старых версия и сейчас био не парсится
В общем

- Находить био по id
- Парсить пользователей из групп (если можно то с bio)

Возможно ли вообще такое сейчас ??

Answer (score 0):

```
result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(id=напиши_тут_id)).stringify()
```